# Python libgtop bindings for Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: gnome, 12.10, python

In-place upgraded from 12.04 to 12.10, and Python import gtop stopped working.

[python-gtop 2.32.0+dfsg-1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/amd64/python-gtop/2.32.0+dfsg-1) (amd64 binary) in ubuntu quantal says **Superseded**

Installing python-gnomedesktop and python-gnome2-desktop-dev did not help.

Where are the Python libgtop bindings for ubuntu quantal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the introspected bindings for new versions of glib-based libraries. In this case, you need to install the `gir1.2-gtop-2.0` package, and use `from gi.repository import GTop` to access the APIs.

Comment: Looks like gir1.2-gtop-2.0 was already installed, and Python can find GTop using that import. Thanks - I'll go udpate my scripts.

Comment: Now where can I find some documentation? The scripts don't work when I use from gi.repository import GTop.

Comment: Unfortunately, use of introspected APIs is not well documented, and can vary a bit across languages. The C documentation http://developer.gnome.org/libgtop/stable/ is a generally good starting point though. You can install `libgtop2-doc` to get a local copy, and `libgtop2-dev` to look at header files, and the `GTop-2.0.gir` file in `/usr/share/gir-1.0/` to look for a bit more details on how some APIs are introspected. If they are flagged `introspected="0"` then they are not available to use in Python.

Comment: Is there a way to use the old static bindings gtop API? What would I risk breaking?

Comment: You can use the static bindings as long as they remain available in the archive. However, you cannot mix static and introspected bindings. If the bindings aren't in the archive, you'd need to build them yourself. It is recommended to migrate if you wish to support newer versions.

Comment: I just want the old scripts to work. If there was an example showing how to do "gtop.proc_mem(self.p).resident" the new way then changing the scripts might seem to be the path of least resistance. As it is, less intelligent thought seems required to find the old bindings and install them.

Comment: I found python-gtop in the archives, and a simple "dpkg -i python-gtop_2.32.0+dfsg-1_amd64.deb" was enough to make the scripts work.

Comment: This is the link that igouy mentioned ( I had some problems finding it too) [https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/amd64/python-gtop/2.32.0+dfsg-1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/amd64/python-gtop/2.32.0+dfsg-1). If anyone comes to a solution with `GTop` please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Everything is moving from static bindings to dynamic bindings through GObject-Introspection.

You should use the **gir1.2-gtop-2.0** package and probably the C-reference for development.

Answer (score 0):

The gnome wiki provides [some information about introspection porting](https://live.gnome.org/PyGObject/IntrospectionPorting).

I found more information by playing around like this --

```
> python
> from gi.repository import GTop
> help(GTop)

> help(GTop.glibtop_proc_mem)

> help(GTop.glibtop_proc_mem().resident)
```

but still not enough to make porting my scripts straightforward.